# When is 前 read さき?

Tags: kanji, readings

I’ve noticed that [Daijisen lists 前](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%85%88-509271) as kanji for さき together with the expected 先. However all compounds at the end of the article include only 先, and I don’t think I’ve ever seen 前 with furigana さき. EDICT only lists it as nanori. Is it actually used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

前 pronounced as さき was [not very rare in the past](https://furigana.info/w/%E5%89%8D:%E3%81%95%E3%81%8D), but in today's standardized Japanese, it's almost never used. You can usually expect 前 comes with furigana if it's intended to be read さき. You can still see it in some proper nouns (e.g., [松前町](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9D%BE%E5%89%8D%E7%94%BA_(%E6%84%9B%E5%AA%9B%E7%9C%8C))).